# xgboostExplainer intercept: and xgboost parameters

Tags: r, machine-learning, boosting

Can somebody shed some light on the xgboostExplainer intercept. I know it reflects the imbalancedness of the data but I have a doubt.

I have one xgboost model with the following parameters

```
params <- list("eta" = 0.1,
               "max_depth" = 9,
               "objective"="binary:logistic",
               "eval_metric"= "auc"
```

For this model I am able to obtain a negative intercept log-odds score of -1.41 which corresponds to a probability (y-axis on the waterfall plot) of approx 0.20 which is perfect since I have approximately 80% of the data as class `0` and 20% of the data as class `1`.

However I run into problems when I assign a `scale_pos_weight` parameter to the model in order to penalise negative cases (0 cases) and assign a higher weight to positive cases (1 cases).

```
params <- list("eta" = 0.1,
               "max_depth" = 9,
               "objective"="binary:logistic",
               "eval_metric"= "auc",
               "scale_pos_weight" = sumneg_cases /  sumpos_cases)
```

Now the intercept of the waterfall plot becomes zero and I do not understand exactly why...

[image]

EDIT: Added image for comments

[image]

EDIT 2: Image 3

[image]

Comment: This makes perfect sense. `scale_pos_weight` gives higher weight to a class, balancing them out in your example - this is reflected in the intercept. Experiment with a balanced and imbalanced data set, change `scale_pos_weight` and see how it influences the intercept.

Comment: I understood from `scale_pos_weight` that we assign a higher weight to the class we are trying to predict (i.e. the 5% in the above example) so we kind of reward the model for correctly predicting a "diseased patient" for example with a `scale_pos_weight`of 95/5 = 19. I kind of do not see the relation to the intercept obtained from the `buildExplainer()`. I know the intercept changes when I assign different values to the `scale_pos_weight` but cannot see why. I still have highly imbalanced data, so the intercept should reflect this, right?

Comment: I know I am missing something connecting the two but cannot see what.

Comment: Alternatively, what would you recommend, use `scale_pos_weight` or `not` and have a negative intercept. when I do not assign a `scale_pos_weight` I obtain (I think, naturally) a low specificity score from the confusion matrix. So assigning a `scale_pos_weight` increases this value and the model is able to perform better at predicting "diseased patients".

Comment: However I liked the fact that the model started from a low probability of "death" (i.e. a negative intercept) since the variables used to predict survivorship had to "push" the log-odds score over 0.50 probabilitiy threshold. If the intercept is set at `0` then it allows for a lot of variation around the 0.50 probability level causing many patients to be miss-classified.

Comment: To illustrate my doubt, I have uploaded two `waterfall` plots from my data. The 0.50 level is the line at the top. The intercept dragged the probability of "being diseased" down significantly and the patient was never able to go above the 0.50 probability threshold and was correctly predicted to be a healthy (non-diseased). However the third image is that of a diseased person that the model had to "fight" to get over the 0.50 probability threshold. The difference being that if I had an intercept set at `0` the second image would miss-classify as it has a lot of variation around 0.50.

Comment: As a side note: I do understand that if the second image actually had an intercept at `0` then it would actually correctly classify that person as being healthy since the final log-odds score (-3.32) is less than the intercept (-3.18) and would therefore obtain a probability of approx 0.49, which is less than the 0.50 threshold. So in my previous comments I was making an assumption and I am sure that there are observations similar to this would which would actually have a final log-odds score greater than -3.18 and would therefore miss-classify with a `0` intercept.

Comment: I like that you like talking to yourself :> @missuse answered your question and I find it to make sense. Nevertheless, I will probably investigate on the package in the upcoming days and see if I can shed some more light to the matter.

Comment: The discussion on this topic is more suited for [cross validated](https://www.google.rs/search?q=cross+validated&rlz=1C1CHBF_enRS772RS772&oq=cross+valdiate&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0l5.3583j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) or [data science](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/). I can only add that the cutoff threshold is a tuning parameter, and no where does it say it should be 0.5. If you tuned the model using auc as metric then you should definitely tune the threshold. That said, the tuned threshold will always be farther off from 0.5 for imbalanced data sets if you do not use `scale_pos_weight`.